Uninitialized array literal
I want to create a pointer that is either an array or a null pointer. Something like
int * arr = (condition) ? int[var] : NULL
but there doesn't seem to be a way of declaring an unnamed, uninitialized, non-constant length array.
I know that I could do it in multiple steps by starting with an uninitialized array and later setting it to NULL based on the condition, but this seems inelegant.
I also know I could use malloc(), but then I must manually free that space.
It seems to me that, since an array is just a pointer to the first element, what I want is not logically inconsistent with C, but I could be wrong.
Is it possible to achieve this in standard C? Is there a fundamental reason why it couldn't work?

"since an array is just a pointer to the first element" No, an array is not a pointer to anything. An array of 5 ints is just 5 ints. It has absolutely no pointers in it. Now, the name of an array in source code "decays to a pointer" in most contexts. That so-called pointer is not equivalent to or any part of the array. It is a source code artifact representing where the implementation is storing the actual array.

There's no obvious benefit from using the conditional operator ?: here. You could just rewrite this code as int a[var]; int* arr = NULL; if(condition) { arr=a; }. "but this seems inelegant" Writing unnecessarily complex or obscure code just for the heck of it is what's inelegant.

If the array was a fixed size, you could do this with a compound literal:
int *arr = condition ? (int[5]){} : NULL;

However you want to use a variable length array.  Such arrays can't be initialized (until C23, in which empty initialization of VLAs is allowed and would be = {}), and as a result a compound literal can't be built for a VLA.
You'll need to stick with one of the alternate methods you proposed, either creating the array and setting the pointer separately:
int size = condition ? var : 1;
int a[size];
int *arr = condition ? a : NULL;

Or using malloc:
int *arr = condition ? malloc(var * sizeof *arr) : NULL;


Which of those two methods to choose depends on whether the pointer value needs to live beyond the block in which the array is declared. That also applies to the compound literal solution, since its lifetime is the current block.

Perhaps var * sizeof *p --> var * sizeof *arr?

This literal's lifetime will be the same as the enclosing block/function.
